# Redoing my bathroom, painting shower glass

Tags: bathroom, paint, glass, remodel

Remodeling my bathroom, I want to know if it's possible to paint the glass door of my shower with some sort of translucent or transparent paint to change the color? The shower side of the door is smooth glass the outside of the door is really heavily textured, what type of paint should I be looking to use?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options.

- **Film**. You can apply a colored film to the glass, this is typical done by spraying it with soapy water, applying the film and using a squeegee to work the bubbles out. You might be limited on colors with this option though.
- **Paint**. Acrylic or Enamel paints can be used although the durability in a constantly wet environment is debatable. If you head down this path I would suggest allowing the paint to fully cure and then applying several coats of clear acrylic to protect it.
- **Stain**. Stain requires the use of a kiln to set the color permanently so this is unlikely to be your choice but it is an option if you have a friendly budget.

Whatever option you choose make sure you have thoroughly cleaned the glass first or you're bound to have issues.

Comment: If you go with film, there are a wide range of pseudo-stained-glass patterns available. Note that anything you do will release light coming in, which may or may not be an issue depending on how (and how well) the space is lit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm open to new ideas and those that think out of the box...however painting glass that is used daily is not recommended.

What can be done is the glass can have a tint or film added such as done to car windows.

Answer (score 1):

Example of (removable) cling film:

[image]

The blue at top and bottom is painter's tape used to fill a gap; the piece I had wasn't quite large enough for this window. Larger pieces, or systems that work like wallpaper and can be built up adjacent to each other do exist; this was an impulse buy 15 years ago when I was shopping for frosting film for a bathroom window.